# Reactjs Rendering a large list of components is slow

Tags: reactjs

I have a page dedicated to showing a list of tags. This list of tags is normally anywhere between 10,000 and 20,000 tags long. I am rendering the tags with the following component:

```js
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.tags.map((tag, i) =>
                <a key={i}>
                    <InlineTag>
                        {tag.name} ({tag.count})
                    </InlineTag>
                </a>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The tags are not paginated as even 10,000 of them barely take up more than a few pages of vertical space.

However, it takes 3-4 seconds to render the tags, which I would like to reduce.

Is there a more optimized way to render these tags?

Comment: You are looking for virtualization, check out libraries like react-window or react-virtuoso. The idea is that you only need to render what the user can see and not all the extra content that is outside the viewport, as the user moves the viewport via scrolling etc the appropriate data is swapped in.

Answer (score 0):

You can page the main tag in chunks and, create a component which will handle that.

For example in case of 10005
Let's have chunk of 10
Then, I will loop 1000 times and get chunks of 10 and render all those 10 in one go and, then We can render remaining in traditional way

Answer (score 0):

you can load 100 tags at first, then in the background make a call to have all tags, once the rest of the data is finished loading successfully, show two more options on the page, "load all tags" and you can also add a pagination, which won't call the server each time but, will have data from it's 1000 tags, that were loaded in the background. This way you can also add an option to filter tags :)